# ES6 SyntaxError with const

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

I'm having this issue running es6 with babel and webpack:

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /Users/agarcia/Projects/app/services/router/router.js: Unexpected token (9:10)
>  9 |     const requestAuth = [
     |           ^
  10 |         '#profile'
  11 |     ];
  12 |
```

Does anyone know what's wrong there?
I'm not sure if I can define a constant in this way.

File:

```
import Backbone from 'backbone';
import Marionette from 'backbone.marionette';
import Session from '../session/session';

class BaseRouter extends Marionette.AppRouter {

   // Routes that need authentication and if user is not authenticated
   // gets redirect to login page
   const requestAuth = [
       '#profile'
   ];

   // Routes that should not be accessible if user is authenticated
   // for example, login, register, forget-password ...
   const preventAccessWhenAuth = [
       '#login'
   ];

   before(params, next) {
       // Checking if user is authenticated or not
       // then check the path if the path requires authentication
       let isAuth, path, needAuth, cancelAccess;

       isAuth = Session.get('authenticated');
       path = Backbone.history.location.hash;
       needAuth = _.contains(this.requestAuth, path);
       cancelAccess = _.contains(this.preventAccessWhenAuth, path);

       if(needAuth && !isAuth) {
           // If user gets redirect to login because wanted to access
           // to a route that requires login, save the path in session
           // to redirect the user back to path after successful login
           Session.set('redirectFrom', path);
           Backbone.history.navigate('login', { trigger : true });
       } else if (isAuth && cancelAccess) {
           // User is authenticated and tries to go to login, register ...
           // so redirect the user to home page
           Backbone.history.navigate('', { trigger : true });
       } else {
           // No problem, handle the route!!
           return next();
       }
   }

   after() {}

   onRoute(route, name, callback) {
      if (!_.isRegExp(route)) route = this._routeToRegExp(route);
      if (_.isFunction(name)) {
          callback = name;
          name = '';
      }
      if (!callback) callback = this[name];

      var router = this;

      Backbone.history.route(route, function(fragment) {
          let args = router._extractParameters(route, fragment);

          let next = function() {
              callback && callback.apply(router, args);
              router.trigger.apply(router, ['route:' + name].concat(args));
              router.trigger('route', name, args);
              Backbone.history.trigger('route', router, name, args);
              router.after.apply(router, args);
          };

          router.before.apply(router, [args, next]);
      });

      return this;
   }
}
```

export default BaseRouter;

Comment: Are you sure this code is being transpiled? Seems to work fine [in the REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=const%20requestAuth%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20'%23profile'%0A%5D%3B)

Comment: what version of babel are you running? are you compiling or is this using `babel/register`

Comment: Yes, just checked, what happen is that I have source-map enabled, that's why it appear like this in the console

Comment: Can you add the lines before the error? This is probably due to a typo on the previous line.

Comment: So with `var` or `let` it works, right ?

Comment: @AndreyBorisko it doesn't like const, if I want this to work like var o let I would set this in the constructor directly, is not what I need

Comment: You, you're getting an error because that's not valid syntax. You can't just shove a `const` into a class definition like that.

Comment: @aganglada it won't work even with `var` or `let` because this is indeed syntax problem

Comment: Thanks @Mathletics I just remember how it has to be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed that simply taking out those constants from the class:

```
import Backbone from 'backbone';
import Marionette from 'backbone.marionette';
import Session from '../session/session';

// Routes that need authentication and if user is not authenticated
// gets redirect to login page
const requestAuth = [
    '#profile
];

// Routes that should not be accessible if user is authenticated
// for example, login, register, forget-password ...
const preventAccessWhenAuth = [
     '#login'
];

class BaseRouter extends Marionette.AppRouter {

   before(params, next) {
       // Checking if user is authenticated or not
       // then check the path if the path requires authentication
       let isAuth, path, needAuth, cancelAccess;

       isAuth = Session.get('authenticated');
       path = Backbone.history.location.hash;
       needAuth = _.contains(requestAuth, path);
       cancelAccess = _.contains(preventAccessWhenAuth, path);

       if(needAuth && !isAuth) {
           // If user gets redirect to login because wanted to access
           // to a route that requires login, save the path in session
           // to redirect the user back to path after successful login
           Session.set('redirectFrom', path);
           Backbone.history.navigate('login', { trigger : true });
       } else if (isAuth && cancelAccess) {
           // User is authenticated and tries to go to login, register ...
           // so redirect the user to home page
           Backbone.history.navigate('', { trigger : true });
       } else {
           // No problem, handle the route!!
           return next();
       }
   }

   after() {}

   onRoute(route, name, callback) {
      if (!_.isRegExp(route)) route = this._routeToRegExp(route);
      if (_.isFunction(name)) {
          callback = name;
          name = '';
      }
      if (!callback) callback = this[name];

      var router = this;

      Backbone.history.route(route, function(fragment) {
          let args = router._extractParameters(route, fragment);

          let next = function() {
              callback && callback.apply(router, args);
              router.trigger.apply(router, ['route:' + name].concat(args));
              router.trigger('route', name, args);
              Backbone.history.trigger('route', router, name, args);
              router.after.apply(router, args);
          };

          router.before.apply(router, [args, next]);
      });

      return this;
   }
}
```

export default BaseRouter;

Answer (score 0):

You can read the [article](http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-classes-final.html) about the syntax of ES6 `class`es.

You can move `const` out of the class or you can just use properties and restrict `set` part of it. It will be read only as well:

```
get MY_CONST() {
    return {a: 1};
}
set MY_CONST(value) {
    console.warn('Readonly!');
}
render() {
    this.MY_CONST = 2;
}
```

You may also add `statics` if needed